# How to access variables in a sub-ccb file with a custom class as root node in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

Let's say I have two ccb files

- **FriendList.ccb**
- **Friend.ccb**

**FriendList.ccb** associate with a class named `FriendList`, it will read nodes from this ccb file with the code like below:

```cpp
CCNodeLoaderLibrary * ccNodeLoaderLibrary = CCNodeLoaderLibrary::sharedCCNodeLoaderLibrary();
CCBReader reader = CCBReader(ccNodeLoaderLibrary);
CCLayer* layer = (CCLayer*)reader.readNodeGraphFromFile("FriendList.ccbi", this);
```

**Friend.ccb** associate with a custom class name `Friend` and a custom loader named `FriendLoader`. It can also contain its own variables, such as `CCLabelTTF`, `CCSprit`.

And in **FriendList.ccb**, it can contains many **Friend.ccb** as sub ccb file.

After these define, I now assume there are two **Friend.ccb** in **FriendList.ccb**, named `m_friend1` and `m_friend2`, and in **Friend.ccb** there is a `CCLabelTTF` name `m_friend_name`.

I load the two instance of `Friend` with the following code in **FriendList.cpp**:

```cpp
bool FriendList::onAssignCCBMemberVariable(CCObject *pTarget, CCString *pMemberVariableName, CCNode *pNode){
    CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE(this, "m_friend1", Friend*, m_friend1);
    CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE(this, "m_friend2", Friend*, m_friend2);
    return false;
}
```

and load the instance of the `CCLabelTTF` with the following code in **Friend.cpp**:

```cpp
bool Friend::onAssignCCBMemberVariable(CCObject *pTarget, CCString *pMemberVariableName, CCNode *pNode){
    CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE(this, "m_friend_name", CCLabelTTF*, m_friend_name);
    return false;
}
```

With these work, I can access `m_friend1` and `m_friend2` successfully, but when accessing `m_friend1->m_friend_name`, I got `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

So how can I access the variables in sub ccb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a sub ccb file associate with a custom clase, we need add a custom loader first.

Let's name it `FriendLoader`, there is the code in **FriendLoader.h**:

```cpp
#include "Friend.h"

/* Forward declaration. */
class CCBReader;
class FriendLoader : public cocos2d::extension::CCLayerLoader {
public:
    CCB_STATIC_NEW_AUTORELEASE_OBJECT_METHOD(FriendLoader, loader);

protected:
    CCB_VIRTUAL_NEW_AUTORELEASE_CREATECCNODE_METHOD(Friend);
};
```

And register it in `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()`:

```cpp
CCNodeLoaderLibrary * ccNodeLoaderLibrary = CCNodeLoaderLibrary::sharedCCNodeLoaderLibrary();
ccNodeLoaderLibrary->registerCCNodeLoader("Friend", FriendLoader::loader());
```

or some other place you like.

Then we can use the custom class(`Friend`) in ccb file. Open **Friend.ccb** file, select the root node, and fill in the 'Custom class' blank with `Friend`.

Then select the `CCLabelTTF` named `m_friend_name`, and select the 'Doc root var', this is **very important ! ! !**.

Here I want give a simple explain.

Since in `FriendList` class, it reads node from ccb file with `reader.readNodeGraphFromFile("FriendList.ccbi", this);`, and using itself as a 'owner', so these variables in it are 'owner var'. When reading nodes, the `CCBReader` will assign these 'owner var' to this 'owner' that is a `FriendList` instance directly.

While `Friend` is a custom class used in CocosBuilder, it is the root node in **Friend.ccb**, and the variable in it is 'Doc root var'. When reading nodes, the `CCBReader` will first read the instances of `Friend`, then assign these 'Doc root var' to these instances.

So what make me failed before is indeed these, I select 'owner var' of all of the variables in both **FriendList.ccb** and **Friend.ccb**.

Then `CCBReader` assign the variable `m_friend_name` in sub **Friend.ccb** to the 'owner'( an instance of `Friend`).

For more information, can see [CocosBuilder: Connecting with cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/develop/Documentation/4c.%20Connecting%20with%20cocos2d-x.md).